# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getServletContext()Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I deployed web project to JBoss 5.2, the server started success but the code `request.getServletContext()` causes an exception.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getServletContext()Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext.
```

It works when I use Tomcat 7.0.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you

Comment: the servlet-api.jar already exists

Comment: I improved the format of your question. Please, add your full stacktrace to receive better help.